# Windows callback function in Golang

Tags: windows, go, dll, event-log

I wanna make [push subscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa385771(v=vs.85).aspx#push) to Windows Event Log in Golang
How exactly should I pass a callback function?

[EVT_SUBSCRIBE_CALLBACK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385577(v=vs.85).aspx) is the pointer of function, like

```
typedef DWORD ( WINAPI *EVT_SUBSCRIBE_CALLBACK)(
   EVT_SUBSCRIBE_NOTIFY_ACTION Action,
   PVOID                       UserContext,
   EVT_HANDLE                  Event
);
```

So, my variant looks like this:

```
func logCallback() syscall.Handle {

    cb := func(_ uintptr, _ uintptr, _ uintptr) uint64 {
        fmt.Printf("callback called %v", data)
        return 0
    }
    ptr := syscall.NewCallback(cb)
    return syscall.Handle(ptr) // type syscall.Handle uintptr
}
```

I get successfully subscribed handler with no errors, but it still doesn't work.
Any ideas why? Where should I look first?

Comment: Looking for any answers.

Comment: If you get no errors.. then how are you measuring that it doesn't work?  What is the expected functionality and what is happening?  How are testing and debugging? Is this all the code... if not can you provide code that can be run local by the community.  Are you importing c?? `import "C"` as the top line https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10973

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Can u write it as answer. (Bounty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using syscall make sure the to include `import "C"`  at the top of your file. Glad it helped you.